# Dockerfile run grunt

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to install `grunt` n Dockerfile stage, I have this command to install `nvm`

```
RUN curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | bash && \
    . ./root/.nvm/nvm.sh && \
    nvm install v8.16.2 && \
    nvm alias default v8.16.2 && \
    npm install -g grunt-cli && \
    grunt --gruntfile Gruntfile.js --target=staging
```

But I get

```
/bin/versions/node/v8.16.2/bin/grunt -> /bin/versions/node/v8.16.2/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt
+ grunt-cli@1.3.2
added 150 packages from 121 contributors in 13.586s
grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface (v1.3.2)

Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.

If you're seeing this message, grunt hasn't been installed locally to
your project. For more information about installing and configuring grunt,
please see the Getting Started guide:

https://gruntjs.com/getting-started
The command '/bin/sh -c curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | bash &&     . ./root/.nvm/nvm.sh &&     nvm install v8.16.2 &&     nvm alias default v8.16.2 &&     npm install -g grunt-cli &&     grunt --gruntfile Gruntfile.js --target=staging' returned a non-zero code: 99
```

Also tried replacing `grunt` with `/bin/versions/node/v8.16.2/bin/grunt`

Comment: See "Working with an existing Grunt project" in the URL in the error message.  (You need to `npm install` before you can run `grunt`.)

Comment: grunt cli is getting installed. I can see in logs